# Are questions about the James Randi Educational Foundation on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

As per [the site description](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12612/skeptics), this is about applied skepticism:

> Beta Q&A site for skeptics, rationalists, free thinkers anyone who questions woo and pseudoscience. Skeptics is aimed at *applied* skepticism; researching specific areas of woo or pseudoscience. It is not for philosophical discussions about skepticism.

As such, wouldn't [this question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7/) be considered off-topic? It's not about applied skepticism; it's about an association advocating skepticism.

PS: I like the question.

Comment: The question was closed

Answer (score 2):

If this question is considered out of the scope, I believe the scope should be adjusted to fit it in. I believe it is a reasonable question topic (not withstanding the minimal research the OP did.)

Answer (score 0):

This is tough one. It's getting in to the murky world of *Skepticism about Skepticism*.

I think the question in its current form is off topic (I however like the question).

Rephrased to something like — For what reasons was the James Randi prize removed.

This can then be answered with **evidence** from the JREF and news reports.

> NB: I *think* is was altered a few years
>   ago or they considered removing it and
>   this is legitimate area for applied
>   skepticism.